# Select element only using data-amount

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reverse engineer my teachers HTML, CSS & JavaScript code, and I encountered an error. I'm supposed to select an element using only the specific data-amount.

```js
function countAmount() {
  var smor = 100;
  var socker = 2.5;
  var agg = 2;
  var mjol = 1;
  var kakao = 3;
  var vaniljsocker = 1;

  var sel = document.getElementById("qtySelect");

  if (sel.value == 1) {}
}
```

```html
<h2>Ingredienser</h2>
<label>Antal kladdkakor</label>
<!-- Label hör alltid ihop med ett någon typ av input-fält, så som select-->
<select id="qtySelect" onchange="countAmount()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>

</select>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <!-- överskriften i tabbellen-->
    <tr>
      <!-- första raden i tabelllen-->
      <th>Mängd</th>
      <!-- th är kolumnen i tabell-headen-->
      <th>Enhet</th>
      <th>Råvara</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- andra raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="100">100</td>
      <!-- td är kolumnen i tabell-body-->
      <td>g</td>
      <td>Smör</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- tredje raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="2.5">2,5</td>
      <td>dl</td>
      <td>Strösocker</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- fjärde raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="2">2</td>
      <td>st</td>
      <td>Ägg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- femte raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="1">1</td>
      <td>dl</td>
      <td>Vetemjöl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- sjätte raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="3">3</td>
      <td>msk</td>
      <td>Kakao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- sjunde raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="1">1</td>
      <td>tsk</td>
      <td>Vaniljsocker</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Keep in mind, I'm not allowed to change any HTML code & my javascript code is pretty empty.

Thanks!

**

### Thanks for the help & sorry for my kinda "fuzzy" question!

**

Comment: What error are you talking about? And what is your actual question?

Comment: I think this is considered cheating. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry to say that your question is not clear and understandable. You can refer here on how to ask good question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you googled for "js target element by data attribute"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like so

```
var el = document.querySelector("td[data-amount ='100']");
```

The above will select the `td` with `data-amount` = 100.

```js
function countAmount() {
  var smor = 100;
  var socker = 2.5;
  var agg = 2;
  var mjol = 1;
  var kakao = 3;
  var vaniljsocker = 1;
  
  var el = document.querySelector("td[data-amount ='100']");

console.log(el);
  
}
```

```html
<h2>Ingredienser</h2>
<label>Antal kladdkakor</label>
<!-- Label hör alltid ihop med ett någon typ av input-fält, så som select-->
<select id="qtySelect" onchange="countAmount()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>

</select>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <!-- överskriften i tabbellen-->
    <tr>
      <!-- första raden i tabelllen-->
      <th>Mängd</th>
      <!-- th är kolumnen i tabell-headen-->
      <th>Enhet</th>
      <th>Råvara</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- andra raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="100">100</td>
      <!-- td är kolumnen i tabell-body-->
      <td>g</td>
      <td>Smör</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- tredje raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="2.5">2,5</td>
      <td>dl</td>
      <td>Strösocker</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- fjärde raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="2">2</td>
      <td>st</td>
      <td>Ägg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- femte raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="1">1</td>
      <td>dl</td>
      <td>Vetemjöl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- sjätte raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="3">3</td>
      <td>msk</td>
      <td>Kakao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- sjunde raden i tabelllen-->
      <td class="amount" data-amount="1">1</td>
      <td>tsk</td>
      <td>Vaniljsocker</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to style HTML elements that have specific attributes or attribute values.

**CSS:**

```
td[data-amount="2"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

> source:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

**JS:**

```
var element = document.querySelector('td[data-amount="2"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like `document.querySelector("[data-amount]")`

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector 
for further references.

Comment: Your answer is partially incorrect. To get Elements list - you should use querySelectorAll, otherwise you're missing value specificity.  Also w3schools is still at this date a really bad resource.